# Should I use string or Value as type in a message for a serialized object?

Tags: c#, json, grpc, grpc-c#

**Goal**
I want to save an object serialized as JSON in a gRPC message.

**Info**
The Microsoft documentation says to use the type `google.protobuf.Value` for JSON.
The serialized object should then be converted with `Value.Parser.ParseJson`.
And converted again on the other side with `JsonFormatter.Default.Format` so that it can then be deserialized.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-8.0#value

**Problem**
It is not explained why.
If I use `string` as type, I do not have to convert it with `Value.Parser.ParseJson`.

**Question**
Is it okay if I use `string` or does `google.protobuf.Value` have an advantage that I don't see?
(You can see differences in the output whether `string` or `google.protobuf.Value` is used.)

**gRPC Message**

```grpc
message PingResponseMessage {
  google.protobuf.Timestamp ResponseTimeUtc = 1;
  string JsonString = 2;
  google.protobuf.Value JsonValue = 3;
}
```

**Create gRPC Message**

```cs
Settings settings = new() {Name = "Dog", Port = 4000};
PingResponseMessage pingResponseMessage = new()
{
    ResponseTimeUtc = Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow),
    JsonString      = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings),
    JsonValue       = Value.Parser.ParseJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings)),
};
```

**Output**

```json
{
    "ResponseTimeUtc": {
        "seconds": "1711525732",
        "nanos": 394125400
    },
    "JsonString": "{\"Name\":\"Dog\",\"Port\":4000}",
    "JsonValue": {
        "struct_value": {
            "fields": {
                "Name": {
                    "string_value": "Dog"
                },
                "Port": {
                    "number_value": 4000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it okay if I use string or does google.protobuf.Value have an advantage that I don't see?

Using `Value` has the advantage that anyone using the structure on the other side doesn't have to parse the JSON themselves, or worry about oddities that particular JSON formatters have (e.g. representations of infinity etc).

If the other side actually wants it *as JSON* (e.g. to deserialize to a different representation using Json.NET or System.Text.Json) then it's *somewhat* inefficient to go via `Value`. On the other hand, the other side might be happy to process it as "the same structure that is normally represented as JSON" (which is basically what `Value` is) in which case they can do so directly without any additional string parsing. (And without worrying about non-standard JSON.)

Answer (score 2):

This started out as a comment but getting too long, so:
I'm not sure that the documentation say what you think it says.
The way I understand it, they simply say that instead of working with the Value methods (i.e. `Value.ForStruct`, `Value.ForBool` etc'), if the value is complex, it might be easier to use `Value.Parser.ParseJson` and give it a json string).

The example they show is for a relatively simple struct with only a couple of properties - and the code for creating and for reading it is quite long and cumbersome in comparison to the code for creating and reading its json equivalent.

That being said, I do think Jon Skeet's answer addressed your question exactly.